# Python: Converting between nested dictionaries and .csv files (generalised)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

For a project I'm having to parse files, extract needed data to file and then use those files for further analysis. I have a majority of it working dictionary to .csv, but am unsure going .csv -> nested dictionary.

**Nested dictionary format**

```
gene_dict[4943] = {'ID': 'SPCC569.02c', 'startpos': '2432505', 'endpos': '2433520', 'len': 1015,
                   'direction': 0, 'chromosome': 3, 'intron': 0},
gene_dict[4944] = {'ID': 'SPCC569.01c', 'startpos': '2434691', 'endpos': '2436530', 'len': 1839,
                   'direction': 0, 'chromosome': 3, 'intron': 0}
```

Where [4943]/ [4944] etc is an index for each entry.

**gene_dict to .csv using pandas**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gene_dict)
df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv(directory + "\\Genes\\" + genome_ID + "_genedict.csv")
```

Irritatingly the .csv this produces doesn't have an A1 entry. (i.e it starts with a comma)

**Main question**

How can I take this .csv and pull in back into Python in the same nested dictionary format as before? I also have other, similar nested dictionaries with variable numbers of entries, and different names, so I would prefer to not have to manually input names/ number of headers.

Other solutions posted on stackoverflow haven't worked for me yet (I've tried pandas pd.read_csv (file, index_col=0, header=, squeeze=True) .to_dict() and some numpy ideas), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds to me like you would be better off [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) your nested dict

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
>>> gene_dict
{4943: {'ID': 'SPCC569.02c',
  'startpos': '2432505',
  'endpos': '2433520',
  'len': 1015,
  'direction': 0,
  'chromosome': 3,
  'intron': 0},
 4944: {'ID': 'SPCC569.01c',
  'startpos': '2434691',
  'endpos': '2436530',
  'len': 1839,
  'direction': 0,
  'chromosome': 3,
  'intron': 0}}
```

Save dataframe to csv file and load it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(gene_dict).transpose()
df1.to_csv('gene.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('gene.csv', index_col=0).astype({'startpos': str, 'endpos': str})
```

Output result:

```
>>> df2.to_dict(orient='index') == gene_dict
True

>>> df2.to_dict(orient='index')
{4943: {'ID': 'SPCC569.02c',
  'startpos': '2432505',
  'endpos': '2433520',
  'len': 1015,
  'direction': 0,
  'chromosome': 3,
  'intron': 0},
 4944: {'ID': 'SPCC569.01c',
  'startpos': '2434691',
  'endpos': '2436530',
  'len': 1839,
  'direction': 0,
  'chromosome': 3,
  'intron': 0}}
```